# How can we schedule 5 reports with 5 users in 1 agent?

Tags: obiee

I have 5 reports want to schedule to 5 emails on 1 agent how can i do this? please help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: First and foremost: Do you REALLY mean "reports" as in BI Publisher objects or are you talking about "analyses" in OBIEE and are just using the word interchangeably? Because they are two different technologies. Please be precise.

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for your reply, Am asking about 'analyses' in obiee 11g or 12c schedule agents

Answer (score 0):

One Agent has one payload - in your case one analysis. That analysis can be sent to as many users as you want. And it can of course be personalized so that the content is specific to each recipient.

Comment: Analysis. Not Report. As I said above and as the documentation clearly states you have ONE payload. Either an analysis, a Briefing Book or a dashboard page.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bi12214/biee/BIEUG/GUID-2419AD39-ECAF-41B0-B28A-C5EABDB371CF.htm#BIEUG280